# Finding similar pictures in a database

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

I have large database of pictures, about a few million.

I need an algorithm to find pictures which are similar to those in the database, up to a scale factor or a crop and shift (I have only these types of variations).

I know about [histogram matching](http://www.sccs.swarthmore.edu/users/01/xianglan/e27/lab2/method1.html) and [perceptual hash](http://www.phash.org/), but is there a faster algorithm that exist for these purposes?

Comment: You're talking about a complete research field, namely Content Based Image Retrieval! Start googling on that for some algorithms :)

Comment: @Geerten I know about CBIR, but I have restricted task.It seems it called 'image copy detection' or 'image duplicate detection'

Comment: The way you described it in your question sounds like CBIR. Maybe you can expand your question a bit more, and provide some more detail about the application?

Comment: @Geerten It's like CBIR, because it's part of CBIR.CBIR is wider task with variable "similarity metric", but at beginning I need just duplicate detection with taking into account only scale,crop,shift.

Comment: Although not about images, but music, I would recommend reading [A highly robust audio fingerprinting system](http://ismir2002.ismir.net/proceedings/02-fp04-2.pdf) to get an idea about the architecture behind this type of copy detection systems. I also think CBIR based on (SIFT) features is promising to deal with cropping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ["Features for Image Retrieval"](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/publications/download/10/DeselaersThomas--FeaturesforImageRetrieval--2003.pdf) text.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use local features like SIFT, SURF, FREAK, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Locality-sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) is one technique, though it is intended for similar in unknown way signals instead of "scaled or cropped and shifted".

I imagine [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) can also be used, but haven't seen it.